# Overloading input operator. Simple fraction class

Tags: c++

let's say I have some simple class called Fraction

```
class Fraction {
    public:
        int num, den;
}
```

What I want to do is to be able to use `cin >>` to fill instance of this class with values.

I've done

```
friend istream & operator>>(istream &in, Fraction &fr){
   char slash = 0;
   in >> fr.num>> slash >> fr.den;  
   return in;
}
```

and it works great when passing fractions like `4/3` and so on.

What I need to do now is be able to pass fractions like `1 2/3` using `cin >>`. 
How can I achieve that? I've tried to convert this stream into string and check for spaces and if space exists then treat total part like new fraction and then add those two but I can't get this thing to work.

My current code

```
friend istream & operator>>(istream &in, Fraction&fr){

    if( false ){
        char slash = 0;
        in >> ul.num>> slash >> ul.den; 
    }else{
        char slash = 0;
        char space = 0;
        int total = 0;
        int numer= 0;
        int denom = 0;
        in >> total >> numer>> slash >> denom ;
        Fraction tot(total), res;
        fr.setNum(numer);
        fr.setDen(denom );
        res = tot + fr;
        fr.setNum(res.num);
        fr.setDen(res.den);
    }
    return in;
}

...

Fraction f1;
cin >> f1;
```

Does anybody have an idea how to do this? It seem like mine is too complicated. Cheers

Comment: @JohnFilleau Ok, edited

Comment: @szulbix Use `std::getline` to get a whole line of input. Then you can convert it to a `std::stringstream` and parse out each "word".

Comment: @super: That would be a way around the problem, but not what OP asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the first number. Try to read 2nd number. If that fails, reset and assume the first number is numer. Then try to read the slash. If that succeeds, read denom.

```
char slash = 0;
int total = 0;
int numer= 0;
int denom = 0;

if (in >> total) { // could also be numer
    // Try to read numer
    if (!(in >> numer)) {
        // Error - could be slash or error
        in.clear();
        numer = total;
        total = 0;
    }
    // Get slash
    while (in >> slash && std::isspace(slash));
    if (in && slash == '/') {
        if (in >> denom) {
            // success
            fr.setNum(denom * total + numer);
            fr.setDen(denom);
            return in;
        }
    }
}
// If here, error
```

Comment: You can't "skip the slash" that way - you need to make sure that it _is_ a slash. Also, you need to separate the different possibilities of error - which aren't just hitting a slash in an unexpected position.